# Restart node server automatically using setInterval

Tags: node.js, cron, settimeout, setinterval

I created a node server that calls an API and displays the data in an `index.js`. I want that the node server (app.js) automatically restarts so the API call gets refreshed every 10 seconds or so and the data is always up-to-date.

Is it possible to wrap the whole code of app.js in a function and use setInterval or setTimeout (also using node forever to restart the server if something has changed)? Or do I need to use schedulers like crontab etc.?

FYI: I am completely new to the programming topic so I would be grateful for any help and advice.

The app.js looks like this:

```js
const something = require("some node module");
async () => {
    const connection = new something({
        email: "email",
        password: "password",
        region: "us",
    });

    const temperature = await connection.getDeviceCurrentTemperature("some ID");
    const humidity = await connection.getDeviceCurrentHumidity("some ID");

    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();

    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

    app.use(express.static("public"));

    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.render("index", { temp: temperature.temperature, hum: humidity.humidity });
    });

    app.listen(8080, () => {
        console.log("Temperature: " + temperature.temperature + " °C, Humidity: " + humidity.humidity + " %");
    });
};
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: Why restart? Wouldn't it be better to read and respond with current temperature on each `GET /` call and leave the server running?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero', how to do so? any hint?

Comment: have a look at my updated answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to restart the whole server to do that. Your `app.listen` is executed only once when your server goes on. But your `app.get` will be called every time a client send a GET request to the path "/".

What you could do is move

```
    const temperature = await connection.getDeviceCurrentTemperature('some ID');
    const humidity = await connection.getDeviceCurrentHumidity('some ID');
```

Inside your `app.get`

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    // you could even parallelize these calls
    const temperature = await connection.getDeviceCurrentTemperature('some ID');
    const humidity = await connection.getDeviceCurrentHumidity('some ID');

    res.render("index", {temp: temperature, hum: humidity});
});
```

This way data will be refreshed at each connection.

Comment: you'd just be missing an `async` before your arrow function for this to work, but it seems like the right solution

Answer (score 0):

Just get the temperature and humidity on a `GET /` call. It's a blind code, hope it works

```js
const something = require('some node module'),
      express = require('express'),
      app = express()
      connection = new something({
          email: 'email',
          password: 'password',
          region: 'us',
      })

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views")

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", {
    temp:   await connection.getDeviceCurrentTemperature('some ID'),
    hum:    await connection.getDeviceCurrentHumidity('some ID')
  })
})

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('server running'))
```

Alternatively, you can load index on `/` without data, and then fetch `/api` with json data on interval, so your page fetches current data (every 10 sec or so) without the need to reload.

```js
app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
  // parallel loading
  const [ temp, hum ] = await Promise.all([
    connection.getDeviceCurrentTemperature('some ID'),
    connection.getDeviceCurrentHumidity('some ID')
  ])
  
  res.json({ temp, hum })
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render("index"))
```

Comment: RE first example: does not display the values from the API call in the index.ejs
RE second example: only displays a JSON string with the values

Comment: @PhGa90 I think the user that answered has already provided sufficient example, you should try to understand the code posted and extrapolate from there to apply your own solution

Comment: @PhGa90, Ad 1) it should pass the data, little more info would be needed if it doesn't. Ad 2) JSON is the point :-) You should [fetch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_api_fetch.asp) it into your site with client side javascript